# How to make the android main activity to 'reload' from outside?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android main activity showing some data which are taken from the database. Now I have a `PreferenceActivity` which is shown when the user wants to change some preference, or delete the content of the database. But if this is the case, how do I force a 'reload' or something of the main activity from a class outside the main activity?

Comment: Use EventBus Or BroadCast .

Comment: Another alternative to this is just to reload your UI in `onResume()` or `onStart()`, as those will be called as your activity is coming back to the foreground.

Comment: I just tried to overwrite `onResume()` and got a runtime error without logcat output...

Answer (score 1):

Set a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` listener in your `MainActivity` to automatically detect any changes in the preferences.

[SharedPreferencesListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html)

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ... {

    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                // Refresh display
                refreshDisplay();
            }
        };

        // Register the listener on the SharedPreferences
        settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

        // Other code
    }

    public void refreshDisplay() {
        // Retrieve entries from sharedPreferences & display them, e.g
        String prefValue1 = settings.getString("key1", "default value 1");
        String prefValue2 = settings.getString("key2", "default value 2");

        // Update UI with these values
    }
}
```

### EDIT:

Here is how your `PreferenceActivity` should be:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // R.xml.settings refers to the XML layout file named "settings"
        // in your res/xml directory
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: But what is  `key`? And how to 'reload' the main activity? Just put in `this.onCreate()`?

Comment: `key` refers to the preference item that changed. & yes, put this in **MainActivity**'s `onCreate` method.

Comment: Does not seem to work. I put a log output in that method, but I do not see the log output if I open my 'settings' dialog and do something in it. Do I need those methiods as well? Put in a caller or something?

Comment: Don't forget to call `setOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` on the `SharedPreferences`. Otherwise, the listener will not get used.

Comment: On what `sharedPreference`? In the piece of code, where I want the main activity to 'reload' its content, is a class derived from `PreferenceActivity`. There is no `sharedPreference`!

Comment: It does not seem that there is a method named `refreshDisplay`. Or do I have to write this on my own?

Comment: @Alex it's defined below `onCreate`. Take a closer look: I added it to make the code more readable. You can discard it if you want.

Comment: But still, the method `onSharedPreferenceChanged` is never called!! I checked that the `SettingsActivity` is as you suggested, and it is!

Comment: Can you update your post with the full code that you have right now ?

Comment: No I cannot. Way too much code. I need to start another project and remove bit by bit to make it postable in a forum like this. This will take a long time. Why must this all be so extremely complicated? Maybe I will just making 'guesses' and hope to solve my problem alone...

Comment: Except I do a log entry instead calling `refreshDisplay`.

Comment: Do you have a `settings.xml` file in the main/res/xml/ directory ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97129/discussion-between-alex-and-sparta).

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to recharge an activity, you can do something like this:

```
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
```